# "data-gid" attribute & W3C XHTML 1.0 Strict validation

Tags: html, w3c

I am trying to get my pages validated using Markup Validation Service on http://validator.w3.org/

Validation against the **XHTML 1.0 Strict** doctype comes back with the following error:

```
... there is no attribute "data-gid"

    …   <a href="#" class="addToCartLink" data-gid="202">Add to Inquiry List</a>
```

Is there any way to workaround this error while staying on the same doctype - **XHTML 1.0 Strict**?

If not, what doctype should be used? What are implications of changing a doctype?

Many thanks, LG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to workaround this error while staying on the same doctype - XHTML 1.0 Strict?

No.

> If not, what doctype should be used?

The HTML 5 Doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

> What are implications of changing a doctype?

You get to validate against something that better represents what browsers actually do, but with tools that are still experimental (although not horribly so) and a specification that is still subject to change (although it is pretty stable now).

Answer (score 0):

`data-` attributes are a feature of HTML 5, they aren't available in earlier versions.

The way you are working is bad practice because it completely breaks when JavaScript does not run.  If you write `href="#"` anywhere, chances are, you're doing something wrong.

If you have an action to take, use a form with a button inside it.  You can include arbitrary data in there with hidden form fields.  You can restyle the button if you wish.

For example:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="gid" value="202" />
        <button type="submit">Add to Inquiry List</button>
    </div>
</form>
```